# X-Frame option error : not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored

Tags: apache2, x-frame-options

I'm struggling with this error, I use apache2 and set a Header :
`Header set X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW-FROM ip"`
`Header set X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW-FROM domain-name"`

but I get this error in the dev tools :

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://wewatch.ml/': 'ALLOW-FROM ip' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ALLOW-FROM is not recognized by most browsers. You should set Content-Security-Policy header with the value "frame-ancestors domain-name;" instead. If you set this, all browsers that understand it will ignore X-Frame-Options. Until IE11 was removed recently I would set both headers as IE11 didn't understand Content-Security-Policy, but would recognize ALLOW-FROM.

Comment: (I'm Bad as "sysadmin" so can you precise in what file ?

Comment: Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors domain-name". Potentially you could also use .htaccess, webserver, or load balancer for this.